# ngx-loading-bar on each http request

Tags: angular11

I am using the the **ngx-loading-bar** to show progress bar on the top of the page. Currently it is only working between the routes. But I want  to also use it when someone doing CRUD in my application.
Here is the code I have added to show the bar **My app.module.ts** class

```
  import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
  import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
 import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
  import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
  import { NZ_I18N } from 'ng-zorro-antd/i18n';
  import { en_US } from 'ng-zorro-antd/i18n';
  import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
   import en from '@angular/common/locales/en';
  import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
  import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
  import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
  import { LoadingBarHttpClientModule } from '@ngx-loading-bar/http-client'; 
   import { LoadingBarRouterModule } from '@ngx-loading-bar/router'; 

   registerLocaleData(en);

    @NgModule({
    declarations: [
  AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
BrowserModule,
AppRoutingModule,
FormsModule,
HttpClientModule,
  BrowserAnimationsModule,
   LoadingBarHttpClientModule,
   LoadingBarRouterModule
 ],
  providers: [{ provide: NZ_I18N, useValue: en_US }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
 })
  export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.html**

```
  <ngx-loading-bar [color]="'orange'" [height]="'4px'"></ngx-loading-bar>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I followed the steps from https://github.com/aitboudad/ngx-loading-bar#1-install-ngx-loading-bar

Any idea what needs to change to also get the progress bar on http requests.